# Index attribute based on other attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We have several models that require children objects

Each children should have a unique sequential ID as primary key and a unique sequential ID based on the relation, like bellow:

```
Object id: 1
  Children id: 1, internal_id: 1
  Children id: 2, internal_id: 2

Object id: 2
  Children id: 3, internal_id: 1
  Children id: 6, internal_id: 2
  Children id: 7, internal_id: 3

Object id: 3
  Children id: 4, internal_id: 1
  Children id: 5, internal_id: 2
  Children id: 8, internal_id: 3
  Children id: 9, internal_id: 4
```

Currently I'm using a `before_save` filter to pin the `internal_id` but I feel this is a bad practice and could be improved with some sql magic

```
def define_internal_id
  self.internal_id = 1 + Children.unscoped.where(parent_id: self.parent_id).count
end
before_save :define_internal_id
```

Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what the acts_as_list gem is for. First, add it to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'acts_as_list'
```

Then in your model, add:

```
acts_as_list column: :internal_id, scope: :parent_id
```

This will number `internal_id` starting at 1, scoped to the `parent_id` column, as in your examples. If you want to start at 0 set the option `top_of_list: 0`.

See the [acts_as_list repo](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) for other options.

Comment: This seems to be working, but I'm not comfortable with the way updates are handled. Is there a way to prevent update on `internal_id`?

Comment: We use `internal_id` to create a tree like structure. I'm not sure how `acts_as_list` handles updates. Could a re-sorting occur without explicitly called?

Comment: Not unless you specifically call one of the resorting method. You should also take a look at the acts_as_tree gem.